# problem of using TIMESAT to processing MODIS NDVI

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, modis, ndvi

I want to use TIMESAT software to analyse time series MODIS NDVI data. Firstly, I use MRT tool to mosaic,subset and project MODIS NDVI data and output data as GEOTIFF format, and save as ENVI standard using ENVI software. secondly, using TSM_imageview to display the image file, and the result is ok. then i use TSM_GUI to open list of image files, the problem is arising--"Error while evaluating uimenu Callback" .[image]

so, if anyone knows the answer, please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you solve this problem? if so, please write the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Did you found the error cause?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, on the first line of image files' list there is no total number of those files.
Or there is a wrong number.

Please, check the list of image files.

[image]